# How to Capitalize Abbreviations and each first word in string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a function which should capitalize each first word in the sentence + it should also capitalize the abbreviated characters.

Example:
a.m.a. archives of general psychiatry -> A.M.A. Archives of General Psychiatry

a.m.a. archives of neurology -> A.M.A. Archives of Neurology

a.m.a. archives of neurology and psychiatry -> A.M.A. Archives of Neurology and Psychiatry

Here is whats I have tried so far:

But no luck so far.

```js
function transform(str) {
  let smallWords = /^(a|an|and|as|at|but|by|en|for|if|in|nor|of|on|or|per|the|to|vs?\.?|via)$/i;
  return str.replace(/[A-Za-z0-9\u00C0-\u00FF]+[^\'\s-]*/g, function(match, index, title) {
    if (index > 0 && index + match.length !== title.length &&
      match.search(smallWords) > -1 && title.charAt(index - 2) !== ":" &&
      (title.charAt(index + match.length) !== '-' || title.charAt(index - 1) === '-') &&
      (title.charAt(index + match.length) !== "'" || title.charAt(index - 1) === "'") &&
      title.charAt(index - 1).search(/[^\s-]/) < 0) {
      return match.toLowerCase();
    }
    if (match.substr(1).search(/[A-Z]|\../) > -1) {
      return match;
    }
    return match.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + match.substr(1);
  });
}

function showRes(str) {
  document.write(transform(str));
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showRes('a.m.a. archives of neurology')">convert</button>
```

Comment: @downvoter — Care to specify valid reason!

Comment: Split the string by spaces, split those strings by dots, and then replace each letter at index[0] with the uppercase version. No need for regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've completely re-written the function:

```js
function transform(str) {
  let smallWords = /^(a|an|and|as|at|but|by|en|for|if|in|nor|of|on|or|per|the|to|vs?\.?|via)$/i;
  let words = str.split(' ');      // Get me an array of separate words

  words = words.map(function(word, index) {
    if (index > 0 && ~word.search(smallWords))
      return word;                 // If it's a small word, don't change it.
    
    if (~word.lastIndexOf('.', 1)) // If it contains periods, it's an abbreviation: Uppercase.
      return word.toUpperCase();   // lastIndexOf to ignore the last character.

    // Capitalize the fist letter if it's not a small word or abbreviation.
    return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substr(1); 
  });
  
  return words.join(' ');
}

console.log(transform('a.m.a. archives of neurology'));
console.log(transform('a.m.a. archives of neurology.'));
console.log(transform('a case study. instit. Quar.'));
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Good point. I've added something to ignore trailing periods

Comment: This is the most elegant answer! Works like charm! Thanks @Cerbrus

Comment: One Issue: It doesn't work with `a case study. instit. Quar.`   `a` remains lowercased

Comment: @VickyGonsalves: That `a` is part of the `smallWords` list. It's blacklisted. The blacklist should be ignored for the first word?

Comment: yup.. is there any workaround? practically it shd be blacklisted when its inside the sentence.

Comment: U are my savior :)